# SABR Model Closed Form Solution

Tags: implied-volatility, stochastic-volatility, sabr

I've been researching the SABR model and one of the main benefits it seems is that you can obtain a closed for solution of the implied BS volatility in certain cases.

In all the papers I've read, I have not found any proofs/reasoning as to where this solution actually comes from.

Does anyone know/can link me to a derivation of it?

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRnR9.png) is the formula I am referring to.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It comes from Heat Kernel expansion and differential geometry.

See Theorem 6 and Section 8 of 
http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1717676&download=yes

Comment: The link is broke. Could you please list the exact title and author of the paper, as well as a working link to it? Thank you.

Comment: New link: https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1717676

Answer (score 1):

The derivation is in "Managing Smile Risk" by Pat Hagan et al. A copy is here:

http://www.math.ku.dk/~rolf/SABR.pdf

It is not closed form, but rather an approximation based on expansions.